# Appstore not recognising bundle id of project generated from same account on xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store, bundle-identifier

During the distribution phase of my app, i have put the app bundle used in xcode to app-store. But app-store cannot able to recognise it even both are in same account. Should i use different bundle id in Appstore?.

[image: Appstore response]

Comment: Maybe you picked a bundle ID that already exists.

Comment: No that bundle id is created by me on xcode.